How to activate maliit on-screen keyboard in KDE Plasma Wayland in Kubuntu 24.04?
I installed maliit-keyboard in Plasma Wayland, and chose it in virtual keyboard.
sudo apt install maliit-keyboard

But it does not show up when I touch a text area.
How to activate it?

The solution is to restart the computer.
Afterward, Maliit Keyboard will come up after pressing the "Input method" entry in the system tray.
However, maliit has a bug that after editing text, if one closes the on-screen-keyboard, it will not come up anymore.
The workaround is to create a .desktop file which will execute pkill maliit-keyboard && maliit-keyboard. Pin this desktop file to the panel so that you can tap it before you need to open up the on-screen keyboard.
Afterward, clicking on the Input Method button will once again bring up the on screen keyboard.
